# Gogland Test Configuration always executed with ./

Tags: testing, go, ide, goland

No matter how I set my build configuration for running my tests the go test tool is always run with ./...

E.G.

[image]

runs:

**go test -v -cover ./... -run ./svs**

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: run my tests inside of gogland.  currently I run the tests in a shell using the following:  go test -v -cover $$(find . -name '*test.go' -not -path './vendor/*' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq) I think the IDE is hardcoded to always use ./... when type directory is selected for the build conf so this is probably a feature request for the team at JB

Comment: Note that if you use Go 1.9 you no longer need to manually exclude the `./vendor/` path, as `go test ./...` will do that automatically for you (yay!) Perhaps updating to 1.9 is an easier way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you need to run you can select different configuration types.

For the one in your picture, Run Kind Directory is selected and that means the IDE will run the tests in the directory you point it at and since the working directory is in the same directory, it will run `./...` as that's what it means.

For the Run Kind Package, it will run only the specified package and no other packages, so no `/...` appended to it.

For the Run Kind File it will run the tests in a single file.

The pattern that you've added, `./svc` tells the go tool how to match test names. There you should put valid patterns for test names. If you want to control for which directory / package the tests are run you can use a different run configuration per directory / package since multiple configurations are possible.

Based on your reply you want to run the tests in your whole projects, recursive, without the vendor folder. To do so, create a Run Kind Directory, as you have one already, and make sure sure you are using Go 1.9 as it will automatically ignore the `vendor` directory when using `./...` matching.

Please let me know if you need further details.